# Send sheet via email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have a workbook called **Status report** which contains several sheets. I need to send **sheet8 (Called tables)** via email.

I generated code but it is giving me errors.

Location of file is on desktop.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub EmailWithOutlook()
    Dim oApp As Object
    Dim oMail As Object
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim wSht As Worksheet
    Dim shtName As String
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
    
    FileName = WB.Worksheets(1).Name
    Kill "C:\Users\Default\Desktop" & "Status report.xlsm"
    On Error GoTo 0
    WB.SaveAs FileName:="C:\Users\Default\Desktop" & "Status report.xlsm"
    
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(0)
    With oMail
        .To = "sleepyyx@gmail.com"
        .Subject = "Test workbook"
        .body = "Hello, could you please check workbook" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
          "I attached you file"
        .Attachments.Add WB.FullName
        .Display
    End With
    
    WB.ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadOnly
    Kill WB.FullName
    WB.Close SaveChanges:=False
       
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set oMail = Nothing
    Set oApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Which errors do you have ?

Comment: Hi @JonathanDelean, error is in this line Kill "C:\Users\Default\Desktop" & "Status report.xlsm"

Comment: Ok, but what the error says ?

Comment: run time error 53, file not found. And then when I go to Debug it gets me to line I copied you in previous comment

Comment: Looks like you need a backslash between the path and filename.

Comment: Also keep in mind that when you `SaveAs` the workbook, you are not saving just that one sheet. You are saving all of them, so your email attachment will include all of the sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Before you kill a File in `Kill "C:\Users\Default\Desktop\" & "Status report.xlsm"`, you need to check if the file exists :

~~> Check if file exists

```
If Dir("C:\Users\Default\Desktop\" & "Status report.xlsm") <> "" Then
 Kill "C:\Users\Default\Desktop\" & "Status report.xlsm"
End If
```

And you forget the backslash

Comment: I added this line and this error is gone but now I have error on line below. Run time error 429. Active X component cant create object. Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") -- I m using IBM lotus notes as email tool.

Comment: If you are not using Outlook, then this is a completely separate question. Your `CreateObject` is meant to be used for Outlook only, and a different application is going to have a different object model, and therefore different code altogether.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37345413/sending-email-through-lotus-notes-using-excel-vba

Comment: For this post, it's solve, accept this answer and post a new question

Answer (score 0):

You probably are trying to use `Filename` from the cell.

Consider using a variable for consistency and in case it changes, and make sure you include the backslash between the path and filename.

```
FileName = WB.Worksheets(1).Name

Dim sFullFile As String
sFullFile = "C:\Users\Default\Desktop\" & FileName

If Dir(sFullFile) <> "" Then Kill sFullFile
WB.SaveAs FileName:=sFullFile
```

Another thing to note is that if you are saving it as an XLSM then the original format also has to be XLSM, or the SaveAs will error if you don't specify the File Format.

[XlFileFormat Enumeration Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat)